# Quickly determine if number divides any element in a set

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic

Is there an algorithm that can quickly determine if a number is a factor of a given set of numbers ?

For example, `12` is a factor of `[24,33,52]` while `5` is not.

Is there a better approach than linear search `O(n)`? The set will contain a few million elements. I don't need to find the number, just a `true` or `false` result.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for **integer factorisation**. AFAIK, this is not a problem for which a polynomial time solution exists outside of quantum computing.

Comment: Is the set ordered ?  Is the range of the elements of the set constrained in any way ?  Optimal algorithms always depend on good knowledge of data, tell us more if you know more.

Comment: The set can be sorted. The range of elements is between 0 - 10^12.

Comment: The set and the number(s) are available only at run-time or one or both can be processed before run-time?

Comment: By "a number", do you mean you want to look for such a number or are you testing one specific number? The former currently has no polynomial algorithm as suggested by Tony The Lion. In the latter case the best algorithm depends on whether you are just testing once, testing many potential factors against a constant sets or testing one potential factor against many sets.

Comment: @Shambool: Only during run-time. I can spend some time initially to process the numbers if it can speed up queries later.

Comment: @smocking: Its the latter and testing potential factors against a constant set

Comment: I don't see that this is akin to factorisation at all.  One (poor) approach would be to generate all the multiples of the sought-for number within the range of the numbers in the set and to search for each of them in turn.  No factorisation (indeed no division) needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

If a large number of numbers are checked against a constant list one possible approach to speed up the process is to factorize the numbers in the list into their prime factors first. Then put the list members in a dictionary and have the prime factors as the keys. Then when a number (potential factor) comes you first factorize it into its prime factors and then use the constructed dictionary to check whether the number is a factor of the numbers which can be potentially multiples of the given number.

Answer (score 0):

I think in general O(n) search is what you will end up with. However, depending on how large the numbers are in general, you can speed up the search considerably assuming that the set is sorted (you mention that it can be) by observing that if you are searching to find a number divisible by D and you have currently scanned x and x is not divisible by D, the next possible candidate is obviously at floor([x + D] / D) * D. That is, if D = 12 and the list is

```
5 11 13 19 22 25 27
```

and you are scanning at 13, the next possible candidate number would be 24. Now depending on the distribution of your input, you can scan forwards using *binary search instead of linear search*, as you are searching now for the least number not less than 24 in the list, and the list is sorted. If D is large then you might save lots of comparisons in this way.

However from pure computational complexity point of view, sorting and then searching is going to be O(n log n), whereas just a linear scan is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

For testing many potential factors against a constant set you should realize that if one element of the set is just a multiple of two others, it is irrelevant and can be removed. This approach is a variation of an ancient algorithm known as the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). Trading start-up time for run-time when testing a huge number of candidates:

1. Pick the smallest number >1 in the set
2. Remove any multiples of that number, **except itself**, from the set
3. Repeat 2 for the next smallest number, for a certain number of iterations. The number of iterations will depend on the trade-off with start-up time

You are now left with a much smaller set to exhaustively test against. For this to be efficient you either want a data structure for your set that allows O(1) removal, like a linked-list, or just replace "removed" elements with zero and then copy non-zero elements into a new container.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the question, so let me ask another: Is 12 a factor of [6,33,52]? It is clear that 12 does not divide 6, 33, or 52. But the factors of 12 are 2*2*3 and the factors of 6, 33 and 52 are 2*2*2*3*3*11*13. All of the factors of 12 are present in the set [6,33,52] in sufficient multiplicity, so you could say that 12 is a factor of [6,33,52].

If you say that 12 is not a factor of [6,33,52], then there is no better solution than testing each number for divisibility by 12; simply perform the division and check the remainder. Thus 6%12=6, 33%12=9, and 52%12=4, so 12 is not a factor of [6.33.52]. But if you say that 12 *is* a factor of [6,33,52], then to determine if a number *f* is a factor of a set *ns*, just multiply the numbers *ns* together sequentially, after each multiplication take the remainder modulo *f*, report *true* immediately if the remainder is ever 0, and report *false* if you reach the end of the list of numbers *ns* without a remainder of 0.

Let's take two examples. First, is 12 a factor of [6,33,52]? The first (trivial) multiplication results in 6 and gives a remainder of 6. Now 6*33=198, dividing by 12 gives a remainder of 6, and we continue. Now 6*52=312 and 312/12=26r0, so we have a remainder of 0 and the result is *true*. Second, is 5 a factor of [24,33,52]? The multiplication chain is 24%5=5, (5*33)%5=2, and (2*52)%5=4, so 5 is not a factor of [24,33,52].

A variant of this algorithm was recently used to [attack](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/02/15/technology/researchers-find-flaw-in-an-online-encryption-method.html?_r=1) the RSA cryptosystem; you can read about how the attack worked [here](http://programmingpraxis.com/2012/03/20/factoring-multiple-rsa-keys/).

Answer (score 0):

Since the set to be searched is fixed any time spent organising the set for search will be time well spent.  If you can get the set in memory, then I expect that a binary tree structure will suit just fine.  On average searching for an element in a binary tree is an `O(log n)` operation.

If you have reason to believe that the numbers in the set are evenly distributed throughout the range `[0..10^12]` then a binary search of a sorted set in memory ought to perform as well as searching a binary tree.  On the other hand, if the middle element in the set (or any subset of the set) is not expected to be close to the middle value in the range encompassed by the set (or subset) then I think the binary tree will have better (practical) performance.

If you can't get the entire set in memory then decomposing it into chunks which will fit into memory and storing those chunks on disk is probably the way to go.  You would store the root and upper branches of the set in memory and use them to index onto the disk.  The depth of the part of the tree which is kept in memory is something you should decide for yourself, but I'd be surprised if you needed more than the root and 2 levels of branch, giving 8 chunks on disk.

Of course, this only solves part of your problem, finding whether a given number is in the set; you really want to find whether the given number is the factor of any number in the set.  As I've suggested in comments I think any approach based on factorising the numbers in the set is hopeless, giving an expected running time beyond polynomial time.

I'd approach this part of the problem the other way round: generate the multiples of the given number and search for each of them.  If your set has `10^7` elements then any given number `N` will have about `(10^7)/N` multiples in the set.  If the given number is drawn at random from the range `[0..10^12]` the mean value of `N` is `0.5*10^12`, which suggests (counter-intuitively) that in most cases you will only have to search for `N` itself.

And yes, I am aware that in many cases you would have to search for many more values.

This approach would parallelise relatively easily.

Answer (score 0):

A fast solution which requires some precomputation:

Organize your set in a binary tree with the following rules:

- Numbers of the set are on the leaves.
- The root of the tree contains `r` the minimum of all prime numbers that divide a number of the set.
- The left subtree correspond to the subset of multiples of `r` (divided by `r` so that `r` won't be repeated infinitly).
- The right subtree correspond to the subset of numbers not multiple of `r`.

If you want to test if a number `N` divides some element of the set, compute its prime decomposition and go through the tree until you reach a leaf. If the leaf contains a number then `N` divides it, else if the leaf is empty then `N` divides no element in the set.

Answer (score 0):

Simply calculate the product of the set and mod the result with the test factor.
In your example
{24,33,52} P=41184

Tf 12:   41184 mod 12 = 0    True
Tf  5:   41184 mod 5  = 4    False

The set can be broken into chunks if calculating the product would overflow the arithmetic of the calculator, but huge numbers are possible by storing a strings.